# Why I cannot send two attchments in PHP mail function?

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to send two attachments in an email using mail() function in PHP, but only attach one.

The problem is in the attachment time, I only receive in the email the first attachment.

Can you help?

This is the code:

```
$from = "postmaster@localhost";
// $to = "hector.oscos@gmail.com";                
$content = file_get_contents($file1);
$content2 = file_get_contents($file2);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
$content2 = chunk_split(base64_encode($content2));
// a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content

$semi_rand = md5(time());
$separator = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

// carriage return type
$eol = "\r\n";

// main header (multipart mandatory)
$headers = "From: Name<" . $from . ">" . $eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol;
$headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message." . $eol;

// message
$body = "--" . $separator . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: text/html;" . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol;
$body .= $message . $eol;

// attachment
$body .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"factura.pdf\"" . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"factura.pdf\"" . $eol;
$body .= "X-Attachment-Id: " . rand(1000, 99999) . $eol;
$body .= $content . $eol;



$body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"factura.xml\"" . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"factura.xml\"" . $eol;
$body .= "X-Attachment-Id: " . rand(1000, 99999) . $eol;
$body .= $content2 . $eol;

// attachment    

$body .= "--" . $separator . "--";
```

mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers))

Comment: Save yourself the heartache and use PHPMailer then you don't have to build your mail by hand

Comment: Although I strongly agree that you should rather use an established library for this job, it looks like you might have simply forgotten to add the boundary value between the two attachments here?